# OpenCV, how to use arrays of points for smoothing and sampling contours?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, sampling

I have a problem to get my head around smoothing and sampling contours in OpenCV (C++ API).
Lets say I have got  sequence of points retrieved from `cv::findContours` (for instance applied on this this image:

[image]

Ultimately, I want

1. To smooth a sequence of points using different kernels.
2. To resize the sequence using different types of interpolations.

After smoothing, I hope to have a result like :

[image]

I also considered drawing my contour in a `cv::Mat`, filtering the Mat (using blur or morphological operations) and re-finding the contours, but is slow and suboptimal. So, ideally, I could do the job using exclusively the point sequence.

I read a few posts on it and naively thought that I could simply convert a `std::vector`(of `cv::Point`) to a `cv::Mat` and then OpenCV functions like blur/resize would do the job for me... but they did not.

Here is what I tried:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ){

    cv::Mat conv,ori;
    ori=cv::imread(argv[1]);
    ori.copyTo(conv);
    cv::cvtColor(ori,ori,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i > hierarchy;

    cv::findContours(ori, contours,hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    for(int k=0;k<100;k += 2){
        cv::Mat smoothCont;

        smoothCont = cv::Mat(contours[0]);
        std::cout<<smoothCont.rows<<"\t"<<smoothCont.cols<<std::endl;
        /* Try smoothing: no modification of the array*/
//        cv::GaussianBlur(smoothCont, smoothCont, cv::Size(k+1,1),k);
        /* Try sampling: "Assertion failed (func != 0) in resize"*/
//        cv::resize(smoothCont,smoothCont,cv::Size(0,0),1,1);
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > v(1);
        smoothCont.copyTo(v[0]);
        cv::drawContours(conv,v,0,cv::Scalar(255,0,0),2,CV_AA);
        std::cout<<k<<std::endl;
        cv::imshow("conv", conv);
        cv::waitKey();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Could anyone explain how to do this ?

In addition, since I am likely to work with much smaller contours, I was wondering how this approach would deal with border effect (e.g.  when smoothing, since contours are circular, the last elements of a sequence must be used to calculate the new value of the first elements...)

Thank you very much for your advices,

**Edit:**

I also tried `cv::approxPolyDP()` but, as you can see, it tends to preserve extremal points (which I want to remove):

Epsilon=0

[image]

Epsilon=6

[image]

Epsilon=12

[image]

Epsilon=24

[image]

**Edit 2:**
As suggested by Ben, it seems that `cv::GaussianBlur()` is not supported but `cv::blur()` is. It looks very much closer to my expectation. Here are my results using it:

k=13

[image]

k=53

[image]

k=103

[image]

To get around the border effect, I did:

```
    cv::copyMakeBorder(smoothCont,smoothCont, (k-1)/2,(k-1)/2 ,0, 0, cv::BORDER_WRAP);
    cv::blur(smoothCont, result, cv::Size(1,k),cv::Point(-1,-1));
    result.rowRange(cv::Range((k-1)/2,1+result.rows-(k-1)/2)).copyTo(v[0]);
```

I am still looking for solutions to interpolate/sample my contour.

Comment: Any idea with resizing the contour to fixed length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Gaussian blurring doesn't work because you're blurring in column direction, but there is only one column. Using `GaussianBlur()` leads to a "feature not implemented" error in OpenCV when trying to copy the vector back to a `cv::Mat` (that's probably why you have this strange `resize()` in your code), but everything works fine using `cv::blur()`, no need to `resize()`. Try Size(0,41) for example. Using `cv::BORDER_WRAP` for the border issue doesn't seem to work either, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065439/how-to-smooth-a-cyclic-column-vector) is another thread of someone who found a workaround for that.

Oh... one more thing: you said that your contours are likely to be much smaller. Smoothing your contour that way will shrink it. The extreme case is `k = size_of_contour`, which results in a single point. So don't choose your k too big.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give that a go now ! The resize is for the 2. "To resize the sequence using different types of interpolations" of my question. For instance, if I have a contour that has 1000 points, I would like to sample it so it has 500 points or 2000 points (using linear interpolation for instance). I thought I could do that applying resize on smoothCont... If not, how do you think I could do.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion (see my edit). Blur seems to be "good-enough". If no one comes with a solution to sample sequences of points soon, I will accept you answer. Thank you again :)

Comment: Is there any solution for resizing the contour?

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the algorithm openFrameworks uses:

https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/openFrameworks/graphics/ofPolyline.cpp#L416-459

It traverses the contour and essentially applies a low-pass filter using the points around it. Should do exactly what you want with low overhead and (there's no reason to do a big filter on an image that's essentially just a contour).

Comment: Here you go! https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/blob/master/libs/openFrameworks/graphics/ofPolyline.inl#L450

Answer (score 1):

How about [approxPolyDP()](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=approxpoly#approxpolydp)?

It uses [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer-Douglas-Peucker_algorithm) algorithm to 'smooth' a contour (basically gettig rid of most of the contour's points and leave the ones that represent a good approximation of your contour)

Comment: Thank you, according to the doc, approxPolyDP() is implementing Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm. As far as I am aware, it simplifies the curve by rejecting points which can result in a curve that is actually sharper that the original.

Comment: The smoothness depends on the epsilon value. If the value is very big, your contour might degenerate to a triangle. If it is small, you just get rid of the noise and basically keep the contour's shape. I don't know what you need exactly, but if you want it very smooth, you could approximate your contour with approxPoly() and use the remaining points as control points for a bezier curve.

Comment: Hey, I just edited my question with pictures to explains why smoothing using this function causes problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

From 2.1 OpenCV doc section [Basic Structures](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html):

```
template<typename T>
explicit Mat::Mat(const vector<T>& vec, bool copyData=false)
```

You probably want to set 2nd param to `true` in:

```
smoothCont = cv::Mat(contours[0]);
```

and try again (this way `cv::GaussianBlur` should be able to modify the data).

Comment: Thank you, I just tried you suggestion, but hard-copying the data from contours[0] did not help. The behaviour is unchanged (no effect of GaussianBlur and cannot resize).

Comment: I will get some code running later to see the problem.
BTW, for the effect in your image, I think "erosion and dilation" (opening and closing) might work, at least for some case, with good params. (or be used before "approxPolyDP" to remove the artifact of that thin line)

Comment: I would appreciate this a lot, thank you. As for erosion / dilatation, it would will work, but in my case, I would have to 1: find contours. 2: calculate how much I want to smooth them (from their size, area, perimeter, ...). 3: draw them. 4: perform morphological operations. 5: find them again while I could just calculate a smooth contour directly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was written a long time ago, but did you tried a big erode followed by a big dilate (opening), and then find the countours? It looks like a simple and fast solution, but I think it could work, at least to some degree.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the sudden changes in contour corresponds to high frequency content. An easy way to smooth your contour would be to find the fourier coefficients assuming the coordinates form a complex plane x + iy and then by eliminating the high frequency coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

My take ... many years later ...!

Maybe two easy ways to do it:

- loop a few times with dilate,blur,erode. And find the contours on that updated shape. I found 6-7 times gives good results.
- create a bounding box of the contour, and draw an ellipse inside the bounded rectangle.

Adding the visual results below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This applies to me. The edges are smoother than before:

```
medianBlur(mat, mat, 7)
morphologyEx(mat, mat, MORPH_OPEN, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(12.0, 12.0)))
val contours = getContours(mat)
```

This is opencv4android code.