# Is it possible to make the segmentation mask boundaries smooth for the training masks in PASCAL-VOC dataset?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, image-segmentation

Instead of Segmentation task, I am **experimenting** with [PASCAL VOC data](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/) data to use it to train a [`U^2 Net for Salient Object detection](https://github.com/xuebinqin/U-2-Net) and [ModeNet as Matting task](https://github.com/ZHKKKe/MODNet).

Idea is to generate a B&W mask image from the coloured mask given (I'll take care of multi class and multi object thing). I can easily do it with 2 lines of code as:

```
img = np.array(Image.open('image1.png'))
img[img != 0] = 255
```

But the real difference between `Matting / SOD` and Segmentation is that the boundaries for the given data are very rough unlike the boundaries of [SOD](https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/kaggle-user-content/o/inbox%2F4863487%2F8460cd9fa778e01445076b0e76a44699%2Fpred_ex2.png?generation=1590928536739915&alt=media) and [Matting](https://i0.wp.com/syncedreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/image-12-1.png?fit=1318%2C524&ssl=1). Is there a way to smooth the boundaries automatically for all the 3K images?

Here are the images, mask and converted B&W mask.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How about performing Gaussian smoothing?

Comment: [Gaussian blur](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_filtering/py_filtering.html#gaussian-filtering)

Comment: You could try to smooth the contours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925777/opencv-how-to-use-arrays-of-points-for-smoothing-and-sampling-contours